# Two subjects require plural or singular form?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, numbers

I am writting an equation for a scientific text, which contains the letters p and q and the letters P and Q as well. And below the equation I want to explain what each letter means: so, I write the equation and then the text

> where p and q label the initial and final electron momenta, whereas the capital letters P and Q are being used to denote the corresponding initial and final momenta of the heavy muon.

Is this grammatically correct? Or do I need to use something like

> where p and q label the initial and the final electron momentum, whereas the capital letters P and Q are being used to denote the corresponding initial and the corresponding final momentum
> of the heavy muon.

Actually I am confused as to whether or not do I need to use the word "the" and whether or not do I use plural and how to combine the two.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain exactly which parts you're interested in, and why you are confused (there are several verbs and several uses of "the" in the passage, and I can guess which you might care about but it's much more useful if you tell us.)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I can try: so, I need to learn if after "p and q" I need to use plural or singular (i.e. momenta or momentum) and if I need to use "the" in front of the word "final" (because I am already using that in front of the word "initial"...

Comment: I hope this makes some more sense :)

Comment: Either works ('where p and q label the initial electron momentum and the final electron momentum' can be deleted to 'where p and q label the initial and the final electron momentum' with no loss of clarity) ... 'the distributive singular' is well recognised. However, purists would probably prefer formal agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where p and q label the initial and final electron momenta

can be written using a pronoun: *where **they** label the initial and final electron momenta* thus the verb agrees with "they".

(NB: This use of the middle voice of the verb "to label" is a little strange...)

> whereas the capital letters P and Q are being used

Here, "P and Q" is in apposition to the true subject "the letters" - "the letters is plural...

Comment: Since the letters "p" and "q" are present in the equation above, I can not refer to them as "they", because among these letters I have other letters as well. So, can I use it as it is? I hear you that using middle voice is a little bit strange. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. *Since the letters "p" and "q" are present in the equation above, I can not refer to them as "they",* I was **not** suggesting that you do this - I was showing you, by example, that, in your example, "p and q" create a plural subject.... 2. where p and q *are, respectively, the labels for* the initial and the final electron momentum,

Comment: Oh okay, I think I get it now. Thanks a lot :). One more question if it is not any inconvenience: I couldn't help but notice your usage of "the" twice. Would it be equivalent to say "... labels for the initial and final electron momenta", using, thus, the word "the" just once and then using plural for the word momentum? Or is it irrelevant?